# How to solve singular linear algebra problem for just one element

Tags: linear-algebra

I am right now confronted with the linear algebra problem:

\begin{equation}
\begin{pmatrix}
m_{11} & m_{12} & m_{13} \\
m_{12} & m_{22} & m_{23} \\
m_{13} & m_{23} & m_{33} \\
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}x \\ y \\z\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}a\\b\\c\end{pmatrix}\,.
\end{equation}

defined on the space of real numbers.  The matrix is symmetric, but unfortunately, the matrix is singular (its determinant vanishes).  Thankfully, all I need is just *one* of $x$ or $y$ or $z$ exclusively in terms of $a$, $b$ and $c$ and elements of the matrix.

Is this problem solvable, and under what conditions (should I be aware of a catch that will mess it up down the road)?  What methods are available at my disposal to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

This cannot always be solved. For instance, the linear equation might have no solutions. Another example is the following: $$\left(\begin{array}{ccc}1 & 1 & 1\\1&1&1\\1&1&1\end{array}\right)\left(\begin{array}{c}x\\y\\z\end{array}\right)=\left(\begin{array}{c}a\\a\\a\end{array}\right)$$ for any $a$. This system reduces to the single equation $x+y+z=a$.

I don't know under what conditions the problem can be solved. I would guess that they are quite complicated.

Answer (score 0):

Well, there is always Kronecker-Capelli theorem: $Mx = y$ is solvable if and only if $\operatorname{rank}(M) = \operatorname{rank}(M|y)$, where $(M|y)$ is the augmented matrix of the system. I can't see how symmetry of the matrix helps, unless there is some clever trick I'm not familiar with. All I can see here is huge casework with Gauss eliminations (which is somewhat lessened by symmetry) if one wants to arrive at particular solution.